# What is the physical meaning of a two-particle wave function?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

A single-particle wave function is specified in three-dimensional configuration space, but a two-particle wave function is specified in six-dimensional space. What is its physical meaning? The square of the modulus of this function in any region of six-dimensional space determines the probability of detecting two particles with a certain relative position in three-dimensional space?

Comment: It's not about *relative* position. See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider this. You have two particles and you want to know what the probability is to find particle 1 at $r_1$ and at the same time particle 2 at $r_2$. Both particles live in the same 3D space but each particle has its own set of three coordinates. The 6 dimensional square modulus wavefunction is the function that answers this question. You provide two sets of coordinates and you obtain the probability density to find particle 1 at $r_1$ under the condition that particle 2 is at $r_2$, which is why a multiparticle wavefunction magnitude squared is a joined probability density function.

I'd also like to make the destinction between probability and probability density. The density is
$$
|\psi(r_1,r_2)|^2
$$

The probability is
$$
P=\int^{r_1+\Delta r_1}_{r_1}\int^{r_2+\Delta r_2}_{r_2}| \psi(r'_1, r'_2)|^2dr'_1dr'_2 \approx |\psi(r_1, r_2)|^2\Delta r_1\Delta r_2
$$
which gives us the probability to find particle 1 in a small volume around $r_1$ and particle 2 in a small volume around $r_2$. By making $\Delta r$ small we can say for practical purposes that the particles are at $r_1$ and $r_2$.

Comment: That is, the square of the magnitude of the wave function in the region r of the six-dimensional configuration space determines the probability of detecting particles 1 and 2 in the regions r1 and r2?

Comment: That sounds about right.

Comment: Which part is wrong? )))

Comment: You should square $|\psi|$ in the last expression.

Comment: @Pedro Thank you for pointing the errors out.

Comment: @Hans Wurst Do you know how to measure the coordinates of a two-particle state? Are you using two devices (essentially two separate measurements), or just one?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян No, I am not sufficiently familiar with experimental techniques.

Comment: @Hans Wurst <You provide two sets of coordinates and you obtain the probability density to find particle 1 at r1 under the condition that particle 2 is at r2> 

Under the condition that particle 2 is found in the region r2. Otherwise, one gets the impression that particle 2 without observation is separately already in the region r2 when the observation of particle 1 is performed.

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume your wavefunction, say $\Psi$, is a function of the positions $\mathbf{x},\,\mathbf{y}$ of two particles. Then $|\Psi|^2$ is the PDF of their positions' joint position. So if $S\subseteq(\Bbb R^3)^2$,$$P((\mathbf{x},\,\mathbf{y})\in S)=\int_S|\Psi(\mathbf{x},\,\mathbf{y})|^2\rm{d}^3\mathbf{x}\rm{d}^3\mathbf{y}.$$

Comment: I didn't understand your answer. Can it be simpler?

Answer (score 1):

The six-dimensional space is the [configuration space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_space_(physics)) of the particles. If the particles have positions $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ in physical space, this configuration is represented by a single point $(\mathbf x , \mathbf y)$ in configuration space. The square of the amplitude of the wave function $|\Psi (\mathbf x , \mathbf y)|^2$ at a point $(\mathbf x , \mathbf y)$ in this configuration space is, roughly speaking, the probability that the particles will have positions $\mathbf x$ and $\mathbf y$ respectively in physical (more precisely, $|\Psi|^2$ is a [probability density function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function)).

Comment: In general, does the wave function occupy the entire configuration space?

Comment: @АрманГаспарян Yes, $\Psi$ is defined at every point in configuration space, but it may of course be zero at some points.

Comment: Exactly zero or very close to zero?

Comment: At a specific time the wave function can be exactly zero at some points. Also, a standing wave, for example, can have a stationary value of zero at certain points.

Comment: At a certain time, that is, immediately after the measurement. It's clear. But our teacher said that in the general case, the wave function, for example, of an electron, astmptotically tends to zero in all space, except for a small region.

Comment: @АрманГаспарян I wasn't talking about the general case or about asymptotic limits.

Comment: That is, you are talking about special cases. Thanks for answers!

Comment: Do you know how to measure the coordinates of a two-particle state? Are you using two devices (essentially two separate measurements), or just one?